# How to handle a lot of HTML as the result of an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was wondering if what I'm doing is fine, it works but I've this obsession to find a possible better way to do it. Basically I've to serve a user profile in a "Modal-box". So a user clicks on a button/link and this window is dynamically generated and its content-div is populated with the result of an AJAX request. Actually the AJAX request calls a php script that get the data from a MySQL database, get an HTML template through the php output-buffer and it stores that file as a string in a variable, then this variable is stored in an array, json-encoded and echoed out as something like that:

```
[ { success: 1, html: "HTML already formatted with data from the PHP script" } ]
```

On the client side, when my AJAX call is done I just fill my modal-content div with the html, so it is something like that:

```
.done( function ( srv-data ) {

   if ( srv-data.success === 1 ){

      $( "#modal-content" ).html( srv-data.html );

   }

});
```

Is this a reasonable way to serve my HTML to the front-end? Or there are better ways to do something similar? I use this solution just for that case where I've a lot of HTML to render with a lot of fields in the database to work with, other AJAX responses are just looped through the Object and rendered on the client side.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "A lot" for an intranet app is quite different from the "a lot" for an internet or mobile app.  "A lot" for IE 6 is very different from "a lot" of Edge.  I say the answer will be primary opinion based.

Comment: I don't know if I really got what you said. But you should generate all the HTML on the client side. I don't see the point to create a different .html file for each user. So, you should pass the HTML in a JSON and then generate the HTML with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a better way of doing things, but here is what I generally do when I have a lot of data to be passed to a modal.

I send the response as a JSON from the server.

So the AJAX request will result in something like this

```
{
    amount: 100,
    approved: 0,
    approved_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    approved_by: "",
    created_at: "2015-12-05 16:24:33",
    id: 2,
    overhead: "dummy data",
    remarks: "Head Approved",
    request_id: 1500002,
    type: "advance",
    updated_at: "2015-12-05 16:29:48",
}
```

Since I already have a structure for the Modal, I can use JQuery to insert the values into the modal.

```
.done(function(data){
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(
$('#proj_id').html(json.proj_id);
$('#overhead').html(json.overhead);
$('#type').html(json.type);
$('#amount').html(json.amount);
$('#projectModal').modal('show');
}
```

In this method, we can send only the data that needs to be sent from the server and the processing happens at the client side. So, the network overhead is minimal. Also, if we are serving JSON, then any kind of client can use the data (Android/Web)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I could use a pre-formatted modal that would work well. But the modal that I use is Dynamically generated from my js-class and its skeleton will serve other sections of the application. I can have a user profile or a forum page or the list of online users into that modal. So I've to re-use the basic markup of the modal for other duties and this is why I try to load an already formatted HTML file into the modal-content.

Comment: Oh, then sending HTML is not a bad idea. In the long run, you might end up sending much more data from the server. If you have a finite list of modals, might I suggest that you parse it in the client side with different functions and send one more field `type` with the JSON to determine whether is a user profile or forum page and so on.

Comment: Thanks man, in the end I separated completely the data from the view using Mustache.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.php",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{

      }
 }).done(function(msg){
    $( "#modal-content" ).html(msg);

   });
```

your code is write on test.php